# How to prevent scrolling body content but allow scrolling navigation on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an "off-canvas navigation" for my page. When the navigation is open, I want the body content to not be scrollable, but I still want to be able to scroll within the navigation menu if it extends beyond the visible area.

I also want the body content to remain in the same position when the menu is open(I found a solution that had me add `position:fixed` to the body when the menu is open, but this causes the page to scroll back to the top).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
  });
});
```

```css
body.menu-open {
  overflow:hidden; /* this does not prevent scrolling in mobile safari */
}

.menu-toggle {
  font-size:40px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

nav {
  background:#fff;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:-100%;
}
  .menu-open nav {
    left:0;
  }
  nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    padding:20px 0 20px 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <header>
    <span class="menu-toggle">=</span>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
        <li>Link 5</li>
        <li>Link 6</li>
        <li>Link 7</li>
        <li>Link 8</li>
        <li>Link 9</li>
        <li>Link 10</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="body-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac magna sollicitudin, tincidunt nisl sed, eleifend diam. Maecenas venenatis semper mauris. In faucibus congue sapien, ultrices efficitur ante pulvinar id. Duis eget egestas sem. Nullam tincidunt purus ut molestie dignissim. Nunc dictum elit arcu. Curabitur vitae magna tortor. Proin lacinia, nisi sit amet gravida pellentesque, orci neque tempor nunc, sit amet lobortis magna nulla id lorem.

Etiam suscipit massa ut diam sollicitudin fringilla ac ac mauris. Vestibulum pretium semper urna. Nulla risus nibh, sollicitudin eget volutpat sit amet, fermentum non enim. Praesent gravida metus in leo pharetra congue. Maecenas augue purus, malesuada tempor venenatis at, maximus at elit. Phasellus ipsum nunc, posuere eu metus in, mattis imperdiet sem. Duis non ultrices mi. Mauris nibh ex, varius vel ipsum vel, fermentum semper tellus. Integer fringilla fringilla pharetra. Vivamus eleifend rhoncus mi at iaculis. Proin suscipit lorem justo. Nulla mauris libero, dapibus a augue et, varius mollis nulla. Etiam iaculis convallis quam. Nulla semper urna vel turpis blandit, in fermentum nunc lobortis. Ut varius dui ac enim fringilla condimentum.

Vivamus in condimentum leo. In ullamcorper lacus quam, elementum dictum elit scelerisque non. Pellentesque commodo augue imperdiet, consequat ipsum ut, ultrices libero. Sed non suscipit nisl. Nam tristique vel ante in condimentum. Morbi et sem pharetra, lacinia eros id, pulvinar enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse elementum ipsum ac scelerisque hendrerit. Ut tellus eros, aliquet sit amet aliquam et, rhoncus a eros.

Donec ut felis ex. Maecenas lobortis risus lacus, vitae vestibulum magna malesuada sit amet. Integer et magna pharetra, egestas lacus non, pretium nisl. Aenean malesuada urna et neque tincidunt tincidunt. In orci ligula, efficitur ut sagittis eget, vestibulum a leo. Phasellus convallis risus et elit sodales, vel sollicitudin arcu elementum. Nulla pretium orci sed aliquet feugiat. Fusce consequat pretium aliquet. Pellentesque dapibus placerat euismod. Aenean eget orci eget enim vestibulum interdum. Donec non enim vel lorem dapibus rhoncus sit amet vel risus. Nulla venenatis egestas mauris, et congue lectus. Etiam ac tristique risus.

Aliquam quis pretium nunc. Sed blandit hendrerit lacus, sit amet posuere velit sodales in. Praesent dapibus viverra turpis. Nam auctor volutpat urna, luctus venenatis nulla venenatis eu. Quisque quis purus vitae lorem blandit elementum a dapibus enim. Donec commodo lectus nec ante pulvinar fermentum. Etiam sodales ex sit amet dolor finibus suscipit. Maecenas luctus placerat congue. Morbi eget viverra lacus. Vivamus ultricies augue at tincidunt luctus. Maecenas vel pretium purus, in egestas nisi.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only way I was able to solve this, after trying a dozen solutions, was the position fixed one along with a scroll restoration bit of JS. If it wasn't for iOS overflow hidden would suffice. Soon we'll hopefully have decent touch-action support (again iOS (or the new IE as I like to call it) holds us back).

Comment: Have you set the body's height anywhere? E.g. `height: 100%`?

Answer (score 7):

Since you have your content on a div you could hide it when the menu is open

Here is a working example

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-open .body-content {
  /* Hide content when menu is open */
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-toggle {
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
}

.menu-open nav {
  left: 0;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <span class="menu-toggle">=</span>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
      <li>Link 4</li>
      <li>Link 5</li>
      <li>Link 6</li>
      <li>Link 7</li>
      <li>Link 8</li>
      <li>Link 9</li>
      <li>Link 10</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="body-content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac magna sollicitudin, tincidunt nisl sed, eleifend diam. Maecenas venenatis semper mauris. In faucibus congue sapien, ultrices efficitur ante pulvinar id. Duis eget egestas sem. Nullam tincidunt
  purus ut molestie dignissim. Nunc dictum elit arcu. Curabitur vitae magna tortor. Proin lacinia, nisi sit amet gravida pellentesque, orci neque tempor nunc, sit amet lobortis magna nulla id lorem. Etiam suscipit massa ut diam sollicitudin fringilla
  ac ac mauris. Vestibulum pretium semper urna. Nulla risus nibh, sollicitudin eget volutpat sit amet, fermentum non enim. Praesent gravida metus in leo pharetra congue. Maecenas augue purus, malesuada tempor venenatis at, maximus at elit. Phasellus ipsum
  nunc, posuere eu metus in, mattis imperdiet sem. Duis non ultrices mi. Mauris nibh ex, varius vel ipsum vel, fermentum semper tellus. Integer fringilla fringilla pharetra. Vivamus eleifend rhoncus mi at iaculis. Proin suscipit lorem justo. Nulla mauris
  libero, dapibus a augue et, varius mollis nulla. Etiam iaculis convallis quam. Nulla semper urna vel turpis blandit, in fermentum nunc lobortis. Ut varius dui ac enim fringilla condimentum. Vivamus in condimentum leo. In ullamcorper lacus quam, elementum
  dictum elit scelerisque non. Pellentesque commodo augue imperdiet, consequat ipsum ut, ultrices libero. Sed non suscipit nisl. Nam tristique vel ante in condimentum. Morbi et sem pharetra, lacinia eros id, pulvinar enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse elementum ipsum ac scelerisque hendrerit. Ut tellus eros, aliquet sit amet aliquam et, rhoncus a eros. Donec ut felis ex. Maecenas lobortis risus lacus, vitae vestibulum magna malesuada sit amet. Integer et magna
  pharetra, egestas lacus non, pretium nisl. Aenean malesuada urna et neque tincidunt tincidunt. In orci ligula, efficitur ut sagittis eget, vestibulum a leo. Phasellus convallis risus et elit sodales, vel sollicitudin arcu elementum. Nulla pretium orci
  sed aliquet feugiat. Fusce consequat pretium aliquet. Pellentesque dapibus placerat euismod. Aenean eget orci eget enim vestibulum interdum. Donec non enim vel lorem dapibus rhoncus sit amet vel risus. Nulla venenatis egestas mauris, et congue lectus.
  Etiam ac tristique risus. Aliquam quis pretium nunc. Sed blandit hendrerit lacus, sit amet posuere velit sodales in. Praesent dapibus viverra turpis. Nam auctor volutpat urna, luctus venenatis nulla venenatis eu. Quisque quis purus vitae lorem blandit
  elementum a dapibus enim. Donec commodo lectus nec ante pulvinar fermentum. Etiam sodales ex sit amet dolor finibus suscipit. Maecenas luctus placerat congue. Morbi eget viverra lacus. Vivamus ultricies augue at tincidunt luctus. Maecenas vel pretium
  purus, in egestas nisi.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately this won't work for my implementation because some of the menu links will scroll to specific areas within the body content.

Comment: Like a single page navigation?

Answer (score 4):

When you trigger the open button, you could have javascript disable scrolling on the body and enable it on the menu. When the menu is closed, the opposite could fire, re enabling scrolling on the body.

On menu open:

```
$(".body-content").css({ overflow: "hidden" });
```

On menu close:

```
$(".body-content").css({ overflow: "auto" });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not prevent the body content from scrolling on mobile

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to css

```
.menu-open header nav {
height: 100vh;
overflow: auto;
}
```

this will make nav to 100% and enable scrolling to it. 
If you want it to be 100% height only in mobile just put it in a @media query

Answer (score 3):

For my website the following worked just find. However, it's important to note that you shouldnt set a height for `body` using this method - e.g. no `height: 100%` for `body.menu-open`, otherwise it will jump to the top every time the nav is opened.

```
body.menu-open{
   overflow: hidden;
}
.menu-open nav{
   overflow: auto;
}
```

And then of course remember your other styles :)

Comment: Unfortunately `overflow:hidden` on `body` doesn't prevent scrolling on mobile safari

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I set your navigation to stay "fixed" at the top of your screen, and just added some jQuery on the navigation, to scroll to different sections in the page.

```js
 $(function () {
            $('.menu-toggle').on('click touch',function () {
                $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
            });

            $('nav li').on('click touch',function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var temp = id.split("_");
                id = temp[1];                                                
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top
                }, 500);


                $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
            });
        });
```

```css
        header {
            position: fixed !important;
            z-index: 10;
            background-color: #FFF;
            display: block;
            width:100%;
            top:0px;
        }


        .body-content{            
            
        }
        
        
        body.menu-open {
            overflow: hidden; /* this does not prevent scrolling in mobile safari */
        }

        .menu-toggle {
            font-size: 40px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        nav {
            background: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            left: -100%;        
        }

        .menu-open nav {
            left: 0;
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }

        nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        nav ul li {
            padding: 20px 0 20px 10px;
        }

        .body-content {
            padding-top:20px;
            position:relative;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <span class="menu-toggle">=</span>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="to_loc1">Link 1</li>
                <li id="to_loc2">Link 2</li>
                <li id="to_loc3">Link 3</li>
                <li id="to_loc4">Link 4</li>
                <li id="to_loc5">Link 5</li>
                <li>Link 6</li>
                <li>Link 7</li>
                <li>Link 8</li>
                <li>Link 9</li>
                <li>Link 10</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="body-content">
        <div id="loc1"><h1>Section 1 </h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac magna sollicitudin, tincidunt nisl sed, eleifend diam. Maecenas venenatis semper mauris. In faucibus congue sapien, ultrices efficitur ante pulvinar id. Duis eget egestas sem. Nullam tincidunt purus ut molestie dignissim. Nunc dictum elit arcu. Curabitur vitae magna tortor. Proin lacinia, nisi sit amet gravida pellentesque, orci neque tempor nunc, sit amet lobortis magna nulla id lorem.</div>

        <div id="loc2"><h1>Section 2 </h1>Etiam suscipit massa ut diam sollicitudin fringilla ac ac mauris. Vestibulum pretium semper urna. Nulla risus nibh, sollicitudin eget volutpat sit amet, fermentum non enim. Praesent gravida metus in leo pharetra congue. Maecenas augue purus, malesuada tempor venenatis at, maximus at elit. Phasellus ipsum nunc, posuere eu metus in, mattis imperdiet sem. Duis non ultrices mi. Mauris nibh ex, varius vel ipsum vel, fermentum semper tellus. Integer fringilla fringilla pharetra. Vivamus eleifend rhoncus mi at iaculis. Proin suscipit lorem justo. Nulla mauris libero, dapibus a augue et, varius mollis nulla. Etiam iaculis convallis quam. Nulla semper urna vel turpis blandit, in fermentum nunc lobortis. Ut varius dui ac enim fringilla condimentum.</div>

        <div id="loc3"><h1>Section 3 </h1>Vivamus in condimentum leo. In ullamcorper lacus quam, elementum dictum elit scelerisque non. Pellentesque commodo augue imperdiet, consequat ipsum ut, ultrices libero. Sed non suscipit nisl. Nam tristique vel ante in condimentum. Morbi et sem pharetra, lacinia eros id, pulvinar enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse elementum ipsum ac scelerisque hendrerit. Ut tellus eros, aliquet sit amet aliquam et, rhoncus a eros.</div>

        <div id="loc4"><h1>Section 4 </h1>Donec ut felis ex. Maecenas lobortis risus lacus, vitae vestibulum magna malesuada sit amet. Integer et magna pharetra, egestas lacus non, pretium nisl. Aenean malesuada urna et neque tincidunt tincidunt. In orci ligula, efficitur ut sagittis eget, vestibulum a leo. Phasellus convallis risus et elit sodales, vel sollicitudin arcu elementum. Nulla pretium orci sed aliquet feugiat. Fusce consequat pretium aliquet. Pellentesque dapibus placerat euismod. Aenean eget orci eget enim vestibulum interdum. Donec non enim vel lorem dapibus rhoncus sit amet vel risus. Nulla venenatis egestas mauris, et congue lectus. Etiam ac tristique risus.</div>

        <div id="loc5"><h1>Section 5 </h1>Aliquam quis pretium nunc. Sed blandit hendrerit lacus, sit amet posuere velit sodales in. Praesent dapibus viverra turpis. Nam auctor volutpat urna, luctus venenatis nulla venenatis eu. Quisque quis purus vitae lorem blandit elementum a dapibus enim. Donec commodo lectus nec ante pulvinar fermentum. Etiam sodales ex sit amet dolor finibus suscipit. Maecenas luctus placerat congue. Morbi eget viverra lacus. Vivamus ultricies augue at tincidunt luctus. Maecenas vel pretium purus, in egestas nisi.</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't seem to work on mobile. The navigation doesn't appear when I click the menu icon.

Comment: I noticed that too.   I changed the menu listener to listen to both click and touch... .on('click touch').  
I can't upload the text code to server at this time, but I'll see if I can look at this tonight.

Comment: I figured out the culprit.
I removed **overflow="hidden"** from the header class.  
Also added 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
so the layout will look larger on mobile.

Just tested it real quick on my server:

http://www.indowill.com/htmltest.html

Answer (score 0):

So this is the best approach I can figure out after a few tries.

You can hide the `body-content` with **jQuery** `toggle()` when the *navigation* is opening, so when it `hide` and `show`, its position will not change.

Make sure to set `overflow-y: scroll;` in `body.menu-open`, so the *navigation* can scroll.

Here is the code:

```js
    $(function () {
      $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
        $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
        $('.body-content').toggle();
      });
    });
```

```css
   body.menu-open {
      overflow-y: scroll;
      /* this does not prevent scrolling in mobile safari */
    }

    .menu-toggle {
      font-size: 40px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    nav {
      background: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: -100%;
    }

    .menu-open nav {
      left: 0;
    }

    nav ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    nav ul li {
      padding: 20px 0 20px 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <span class="menu-toggle">=</span>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
        <li>Link 5</li>
        <li>Link 6</li>
        <li>Link 7</li>
        <li>Link 8</li>
        <li>Link 9</li>
        <li>Link 10</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="body-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac magna sollicitudin, tincidunt nisl sed, eleifend diam. Maecenas
    venenatis semper mauris. In faucibus congue sapien, ultrices efficitur ante pulvinar id. Duis eget egestas sem. Nullam
    tincidunt purus ut molestie dignissim. Nunc dictum elit arcu. Curabitur vitae magna tortor. Proin lacinia, nisi sit amet
    gravida pellentesque, orci neque tempor nunc, sit amet lobortis magna nulla id lorem. Etiam suscipit massa ut diam sollicitudin
    fringilla ac ac mauris. Vestibulum pretium semper urna. Nulla risus nibh, sollicitudin eget volutpat sit amet, fermentum
    non enim. Praesent gravida metus in leo pharetra congue. Maecenas augue purus, malesuada tempor venenatis at, maximus
    at elit. Phasellus ipsum nunc, posuere eu metus in, mattis imperdiet sem. Duis non ultrices mi. Mauris nibh ex, varius
    vel ipsum vel, fermentum semper tellus. Integer fringilla fringilla pharetra. Vivamus eleifend rhoncus mi at iaculis.
    Proin suscipit lorem justo. Nulla mauris libero, dapibus a augue et, varius mollis nulla. Etiam iaculis convallis quam.
    Nulla semper urna vel turpis blandit, in fermentum nunc lobortis. Ut varius dui ac enim fringilla condimentum. Vivamus
    in condimentum leo. In ullamcorper lacus quam, elementum dictum elit scelerisque non. Pellentesque commodo augue imperdiet,
    consequat ipsum ut, ultrices libero. Sed non suscipit nisl. Nam tristique vel ante in condimentum. Morbi et sem pharetra,
    lacinia eros id, pulvinar enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse elementum ipsum
    ac scelerisque hendrerit. Ut tellus eros, aliquet sit amet aliquam et, rhoncus a eros. Donec ut felis ex. Maecenas lobortis
    risus lacus, vitae vestibulum magna malesuada sit amet. Integer et magna pharetra, egestas lacus non, pretium nisl. Aenean
    malesuada urna et neque tincidunt tincidunt. In orci ligula, efficitur ut sagittis eget, vestibulum a leo. Phasellus
    convallis risus et elit sodales, vel sollicitudin arcu elementum. Nulla pretium orci sed aliquet feugiat. Fusce consequat
    pretium aliquet. Pellentesque dapibus placerat euismod. Aenean eget orci eget enim vestibulum interdum. Donec non enim
    vel lorem dapibus rhoncus sit amet vel risus. Nulla venenatis egestas mauris, et congue lectus. Etiam ac tristique risus.
    Aliquam quis pretium nunc. Sed blandit hendrerit lacus, sit amet posuere velit sodales in. Praesent dapibus viverra turpis.
    Nam auctor volutpat urna, luctus venenatis nulla venenatis eu. Quisque quis purus vitae lorem blandit elementum a dapibus
    enim. Donec commodo lectus nec ante pulvinar fermentum. Etiam sodales ex sit amet dolor finibus suscipit. Maecenas luctus
    placerat congue. Morbi eget viverra lacus. Vivamus ultricies augue at tincidunt luctus. Maecenas vel pretium purus, in
    egestas nisi.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```